# Why does this lapply inside a within call differ from this variable assignment inside the within call?

Tags: r, with-statement, r-factor

Consider:

```
notBroken<-within(mtcars, {
  gear<-as.factor(gear)
  cyl<-as.factor(cyl)})
str(notBroken)
```

Our output,

```
> str(notBroken)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: Factor w/ 3 levels "3","4","5": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

shows that `cyl` and `gear` have become factors, as desired. However, this:

```
broken<-within(mtcars,lapply(list(gear,cyl),as.factor))
str(broken)
```

does not do the same.

```
> str(broken)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

Why?

I suspect that it might have something to do with how `with(mtcars,gear)` shows that `within` treats `gear` like `mtcars$gear` and not `mtcars["gear"]`, but that's not a full answer. Was what I was trying to do in this way possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `lapply()` does not assign the output to the variables `gear` and `cyl` of `broken` (e.g. no changes occurred to `broken`).

```
broken<-within(mtcars, gear <- unlist(lapply(list(gear), as.factor)))
str(broken)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: Factor w/ 3 levels "3","4","5": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

Comparing to `with`:

```
x <- with(mtcars, lapply(list(gear, cyl), as.factor))
str(x)
List of 2
 $ : Factor w/ 3 levels "3","4","5": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ...
```